# Draw a Line on Canvas With Mouse Position Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I followed a tutorial to draw a line using mouse position, the line will be drawn inside the canvas. But when running it, the line didn't drawn! and it gives me this error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

What's wrong in my code?

Here's the script:

```
public GameObject Line;
GameObject CurrentLine;
LineRenderer linerenderer;
private List<Vector2> FingerPositions;
public Canvas Can;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        CreateLine();
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        Vector2 tempfingerpos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Vector2.Distance(tempfingerpos, FingerPositions[FingerPositions.Count - 1]) > 0.1f)
        {
            UpdateLine(tempfingerpos);
        }
    }
}

void CreateLine()
{
    CurrentLine = Instantiate(Line, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
    linerenderer = CurrentLine.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    FingerPositions.Clear();
    FingerPositions.Add(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition));
    FingerPositions.Add(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition));
    linerenderer.SetPosition(0, FingerPositions[0]);
    linerenderer.SetPosition(0, FingerPositions[1]);
    CurrentLine.transform.SetParent(Can.transform, false);
}

void UpdateLine(Vector2 NewFingerPos)
{
    FingerPositions.Add(NewFingerPos);
    linerenderer.positionCount ++;
    linerenderer.SetPosition(linerenderer.positionCount - 1, NewFingerPos);
}
```

Comment: What line is throwing the error?

Comment: @TheBatman This one:   if(Vector2.Distance(tempfingerpos, FingerPositions[FingerPositions.Count - 1]) > 0.1f)

Comment: You need to initialize FingerPositions before you can use it. Are you running `FingerPositions = new List<Vector2>()` in your `Start()` method?

Comment: @TheBatman Yeah you"re right, but I got only a horizontal line that never changed with mouse position, and also he is in the worldspace not inside the canvas, even if he is inside it in the hierarchy!!

Comment: How old is this tutorial? Unity, and C# for that matter, have changed a lot since the early days of Unity 3D, particularly in the last 3 years or so. Its possible that the code in the tutorial is no longer valid in today's Unity. If you can, try to match the version of Unity that the tutorial is using or try to find a more modern tutorial (if it is in fact very old). Otherwise I'll take a crack at this over the weekend when I'm not on the clock and see if I can figure out whats going on here :)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to try first to draw line renderer with fixed positions(You can add two empty objects and then draw line renderer between those objects).
And if that works, then move to the logic with fingers.
Keep in mind that you can't see line renderer if you are using screen space overlay, so you must use Canvas - World Space to see it over the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

replace this
private List FingerPositions;
with this

```
    private List<Vector2>  FingerPositions = new List<Vector2>();
```

Comment: Maybe you can provide some additional information as to why this would work.